# Showing an alert view in Swift causes EXC BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following view controller. It simply reads from a text field a value to display in a `UIAlertView`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func pressButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let name = textField.text

        let alert = UIAlertView(
            title: "Hello!",
            message: "How are you today, \(name). I'm lovely!",
            delegate: nil,
            cancelButtonTitle: "Thanks!"
        )

        alert.show() // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }
}
```

Why does `alert.show()` crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? What's happening here to my instance of `UIAlertView`? Why isn't it in `alert` like I think it should be?

Comment: I assumed it was a syntax issue I wasn't getting. Apologies!

Comment: Haven't `UIAlertView`s been replaced with `UIAlertController` in iOS8?

Answer (score 9):

Try to use var instead of lat as following

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: how can i call delegate method of alert.

Comment: @iOS Developer this causes the background view get black & generates the warning, `presenting view on deteched view controllers is discouraged`